# Integrating node.js and express website with wordpress hosting

Tags: node.js, wordpress, integration

I have a website running on node.js and express, hosted on Amazon EC2 with a normal domain (e.g. www.example.com)

We want to add a blog to the website.  We would like the blog route to be www.example.com/blog

I have tried a Ghost installation under node.js (with a proxy layer to handle the port and url remap).  I got it working ok, but the feature set is not robust enough for our content creators.  They would rather work with WordPress.

But WordPress does not have a node.js install, and I do not have the bandwidth to set up and run a WAMP server in addition to the node.js server we currently use.

So I am investigating using a another hosting option for wordpress and using a proxy layer to redirect to the hosted wordpress blog.

From what I have read online, WordPress hosting will not work (cannot configure the URL properly on the WordPress side).  And I could not get the proxy layer to work with a test account.

Will a 3rd party (like GoDaddy) work?

I am envisioning that we host the blog on GoDaddy.  And on our site, I set up a proxy to map www.coursehunter.org/blog to the GoDaddy hosted Wordpress blog.  Has anyone done this?  Does it work technically?  I understand I would probably have to edit the .htaccess file.

Are there SEO gotchyas from an implementation perspective?  The main point of our blog is to build out content for our main domain which is why we want the www.example.com/blog url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you look into Nginx web server. You can set it up as a reverse proxy for your NodeJS/Express web application and install its `php-fpm` module to handle the PHP part(Wordpress).

Here is a guide to set up Wordpress with Nginx https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

And here is one with set up your NodeJS application with Nginx https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

In your case, you will need to setup the url configuration so that the parts get routed to the correct destination that is NodeJS part is handled by reverse proxy and Wordpress is handled by `php-fpm`

Comment: I guess you can also use nginx [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive instead of touching NodeJS - it's just an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I am trying to avoid adding an nginx layer at the moment.  It seems like I should be able to use npm module http-proxy to do the proxy redirect from my node express server to wordpress once it's configured correctly.