# Is it possible to run a Node.js application synchronously with a Node server?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express, woocommerce

I want to play around with the WooCommerce API and it needs an authorization key that you can generate through your WordPress site. So I'd like to make setup a server with Express, install WordPress on it and then run an app made in a separate app.js file and run it with Node to communicate with that Express server.

I'm new to programming so this might be a "dumb" question, but normally when I start my server with nodemon in de command line, I can't run additional files. I need to close the server first with ctrl + C. Is what I want to do possible, maybe with two terminal screens? Or do I have to download an additional server to run WordPress on, like MAMP?

Thanks!

Comment: Wordpress is written in PHP. Express is written in Javascript. You can't really run PHP applications in Node.js/Javascript and need something that can support PHP

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! In that case, I'll use something like MAMP or Flywheel. :)

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975551/integrating-node-js-and-express-website-with-wordpress-hosting. I hope it will helps you.